# Is there ever a reason to use variable variables in PHP rather than an array?

Tags: php, variables, array

Is there *any* situation where an `array` is not suitable but a `variable variable` is? I cannot think of one or find one on any Stack Programmer Q&A.

```
<?php

$foo = array();
for($i = 0;$i < 3; $i++){

    $foo[$i] = "bar ".$i;


}

var_dump($foo); // ["bar 0", "bar 1", "bar 2"]

for($i = 0;$i < 3; $i++){

    $foo = "bar".$i;

    $$foo = "baz ".$i;


}

echo $bar0; //baz 0
echo $bar1; //baz 1
echo $bar2; //baz 2

?>
```

Comment: The only reasonable use I can think of for variable variables is templating.  Templating is a form of metaprogramming for which variable variables seem uniquely suitable.  See http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/101

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what arrays and variables are meant to represent.  I think the only proper answer is "use them more and see which is easier" because some things need to be experienced rather than explained.

Comment: Understood, I guess I just need to come across that situation where I need to use it. The question itself was more of a response to the amount of questions on SO where people ask how to use VVs when they should be using an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a reason or specific case. The only example I have (one implementation - not mine) is in an OOP approach where you may build classes/ objects dynamically and use $$vars.

Personally, I don't like my code/ interfaces to be this open. I tend to use arrays if I am unsure of my properties and then once I know what I need, make them individual properties.